# How do I reload system settings from command line on Kubuntu?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde, kde4, system-settings

To better understand what I need: In systemsettings (KDE), in icon theme module, after I change the icon theme, I click apply. I need to know which command line I run to do the same when I click apply button. It is qbus related?

Comment: First, it isn't QBus related, second, you can usually change KDE configuration from ~/.kde4/share or ~/.config. It is sort of hard to find the configuration file though :/

Comment: Yep, I know where the configuration files are located. What I do know is how to apply the changes. Not simply change settings values in files and save. You need to run some command to apply the changes, what? Ahh, and without the need to reboot

Comment: Oh, I see... something like a restart of the KDE settings daemon, right?

Comment: Exactly! Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use KDE... was just throwing suggestions :)

Comment: This doesn't really help, but I was looking for a similar solution here. http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=108974 I tried a few different suggestions, but none really worked.

Answer (score 0):

The command to reload the KDE configuration is:

```
$ kbuildsycoca4
```

But I can not test it with the icon theme, because you have not mentioned where exactly is the icon theme config located and it's not so obvious to me.